# How to update column data in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I am using TDengine to store time-series data with multiple columns. TDengine has the ability to update the whole row with database `update` option setting as 1. How can I just update partial columns of a row instead of the whole row?

Answer (score 0):

From TDengine 2.1.7.0, you can update partial columns of a row by using [update](/questions/tagged/update) option 2, but there are some limitations:

1. you cannot switch from option 1 to option 2 by using command: `alter database db update 2` which is not allowed by design
2. If a NULL value is provided for a field, this field won't be updated